# No funciona RemoveAttr, que puede ser?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, mvc

Tengo el siguiente código para la validación de las reglas, al final agrego una función anonima que se dispara cuando el primero cambia el dato, pero el removeAttr no funciona.

Alguien sabe Por que no funciona o que tengo mal en mi código y por eso no funciona?

He buscado en muchas páginas la solución a este problema, pero ninguna ha resuelto la duda o la forma en que pueda realizar la solución.

```
@nameCustodianOne: function (input) {
    if (input.is("[name=@nameCustodianOne]")) {
        if (input.val() == $("[name=@nameCustodianTwo]").val() && input.val().length !== 0) {
            input.attr("data-@nameCustodianOne-msg", "@WebUiFormResource.DuplicatedUser");
            return false;
        }
        else if (input.val() != $("[name=@nameCustodianTwo]").val() && input.val().length !== 0 && $("[name=@nameCustodianTwo]").val().length !== 0) {
            input.attr("data-@nameCustodianOne-msg", "Prueba Uno");
            return false;
        }
        else if (input.val() == $("[name=@nameGuarantor]").val() && input.val().length !== 0) {
            input.attr("data-@nameCustodianOne-msg", "@WebUiFormResource.DuplicatedUser");
            return false;
        }
        if (input.val().length == 0) {
            input.attr("data-@nameCustodianOne-msg", "@WebUiFormResource.Required");
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
},
@nameCustodianTwo: function(input) {
    if (input.is("[name=@nameCustodianTwo]")) {
        if (input.val() == $("[name=@nameCustodianOne]").val() && input.val().length !== 0) {
            input.attr("data-@nameCustodianTwo-msg", "@WebUiFormResource.DuplicatedUser");
            return false;
        }
        else if (input.val() != $("[name=@nameCustodianOne]").val() && input.val().length !== 0 && $("[name=@nameCustodianOne]").val().length !== 0) {
            input.attr("data-@nameCustodianTwo-msg", "Prueba Dos");
            return false;
        }
        else if (input.val() == $("[name=@nameGuarantor]").val() && input.val().length !== 0) {
            input.attr("data-@nameCustodianTwo-msg", "@WebUiFormResource.DuplicatedUser");
            return false;
        }
        if (input.val().length == 0) {
            input.attr("data-@nameCustodianTwo-msg", "@WebUiFormResource.Required");
            return false;
        }
    }
    $("[name=@nameCustodianOne]").click("change", function () {
        let nameOne = $("[name=@nameCustodianOne]").val();
        let nameTwo = $("[name=@nameCustodianTwo]").val();

        if (nameOne != nameTwo && nameOne.length !== 0 && nameTwo.length !== 0) {
            $("[name=@nameCustodianTwo]").removeAttr("data-@nameCustodianTwo-msg");
        }

    });
    return true;
},
```

Gracias.

Comment: en jquery hay funciones especificas para los data-* attributes `$.data()` y `$.RemoveData()`

Comment: Pero con el `$.RemoveData()` tampoco funciona.

Comment: si ya te leiste el ejemplo del [data](https://api.jquery.com/data/) y del [removeData](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.removedata/#:~:text=removeData()%20method%20allows%20us,arguments%2C%20all%20values%20are%20removed.) trata de poner los tipicos mensajes de consola con `console.log` para verificar los objetos en los evento change

Comment: Los objetos los recibe bien, pero no funciona ni el `$.RemoveData()` ni el `$.RemoveAttr()`

Comment: A todo esto... Se entiende que has comprobado si entra en el `if (nameOne != nameTwo && nameOne.length !== 0 && nameTwo.length !== 0) {`, ¿verdad?

Comment: Exacto, la función entra, pero no ejecuta el código que tiene que esta dentro de esa condición

Comment: Lo que quiero decir es... ¿entra en el if? Es que si no entra, no que no funcione `removeAttr` como indica la pregunta. Estaría bien hacer un `console.log(nameOne ," - ",nameTwo)` justo antes del IF para ver lo que sale

Comment: Se realizo el `console.log` a `nameOne` y  `nameTwo` y cada uno trae la info y cuando se cumple el `if` este entra pero no ejecuta lo que esta dentro del `if`